# Efficient wat to capture osx 10.8 screen

Tags: macos, screenshot

Im truing to capture screen for processing and maybe record a video or something, but CGDisplayCreateImage appears to be inefficient it toke 0.023808 s

code:

```
NSDate* timingDate = [NSDate date];
cgi_image = CGDisplayCreateImage(mainDisplay);
NSLog(@"Time taken: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: timingDate]);
```

i read something abour framebuffer and opengl but none work, any advice ?

regrads.

Comment: Note that, if you just need to record a video, QuickTime Player can do that. (File > New Screen Recording)

Comment: I need to do some "realtime" processing in frames.